# Commerce - Hide Add-to-Cart form from Anonymous users

Tags: commerce, users

I am constructing a site that will serve mainly agents (authenticated users), but should still show all of the products (without prices) for anonymous users. When logged in, only agents should see the Add-to-Cart form on the product display page, and anonymous users should instead see a link to an "Ask a Question" page.

Is this possible? I looked through the permissions table and could not find a way to prevent access to the cart form by anonymous users.

The only thing I can think of doing is customizing my `node--product-display.tpl.php` file:

```
<?php  
    if ($logged_in) {
      print render($page['content']);
  } else {
      // something else
  }
?>
```

I'll have to print the rest of my fields out manually, but as far as I know, this is the only way to print the *Add to Cart* form. I'm a bit uneasy about this, so I'm humbly looking here for another solution.  thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the link : http://www.drupalcommerce.org/node/2528 with an condition for anonymous user added.

> It's taken me a while but I've finally cracked it! I've used
>   hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() (that took me some learning and meant I had
>   to create my own, admittedly trivial, module!). So in my module I've
>   got the following which sets #access for the submit form to false
>   which stops it being rendered (see
>   http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_referenc...).
>
> In the future, I'll be able to extend this to disable the button on
>   certain conditions (say when there's no stock but I want to show what
>   combinations are possible). It would also presumably be an easy way of
>   changing, say, the text for the button, such as "Buy" instead of "Add
>   to cart".

```
  function mymodule_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
global $user;
    if ($user->uid == 0) {
    // Disable the Add to Cart submit button


  $form['submit'] = array('#access' => FALSE);
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Harshal! Let me try this out and I'll let you know

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but that worked like a charm. thanks!

Comment: I just customized this to see if the user was also in a specific role

Comment: @maGz Please share your code. It may be helpful for others.

Comment: @Kevin: you're right, although this was a while back and I'll have to look through my backups to pull that out. Will try an make some time this evening to get this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I added a notice to the accepted answer.

```
function hook_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid == 0) {
    // Disable the Add to Cart submit button
    $form['submit'] = array('#access' => FALSE);
    // Display notice to login
    $form['notice'] = array(
      '#prefix' => '<div class="login-notice">',
      '#markup' => t('<a href="/user/login">Login</a> / <a href="/user/register">Register</a> to buy this product before its gone.'),
      '#suffix' => '</div>', 
    );
  }
}
```